# Cascade save on OrientDB Document API when using embedded types

Tags: orientdb, nosql

Given the following test:

```java
    // setup
    OClass driver = getDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(DRIVER);
    OClass car = getDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(CAR);
    car.createProperty(DRIVERS, OType.EMBEDDEDLIST, driver);
    OClass team = getDatabase().getMetadata().getSchema().createClass(TEAM);
    team.createProperty(CARS, OType.EMBEDDEDSET, car);

    // exercise
    ODocument alonso = new ODocument(DRIVER).field("name", "Fernando Alonso").field("nationality", "Spanish")
            .field("yearOfBirth", 1981);
    ODocument button = new ODocument(DRIVER).field("name", "Jenson Button").field("nationality", "british")
            .field("yearOfBirth", 1980);
    ODocument mp30 = new ODocument(CAR).field(DRIVERS, Arrays.asList(new ODocument[] { alonso, button }));
    Set<ODocument> cars = new HashSet<>();
    cars.add(mp30);
    ODocument mclarenF1Team = new ODocument(TEAM).field(CARS, cars);

    mclarenF1Team.save();

    // verify
    assertEquals(1, getDatabase().countClass(TEAM));
    assertEquals(1, getDatabase().countClass(CAR));
    assertEquals(2, getDatabase().countClass(DRIVER));
```

The second assertion fails:

> java.lang.AssertionError: expected:<1> but was:<0>
>       at org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)
>       at org.junit.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:834)
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:645)
>       at org.junit.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:631)
>       at foo.orientdb.dataaccessapi.StoreJSonIT.testSchemaFull(StoreJSonIT.java:68)

Why does it fail?

The properties CAR and DRIVER are created as **embedded list** and **embedded set**, shouldn't a single save in *mclarenF1Team* do a cascade save for the embedded documents?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Embedded List/Set means that the documents you create will be embedded (Saved) in the parent document and not in his own class/cluster.

IF you want to achieve that behaviour you should use links

See here

http://orientdb.com/docs/2.1/Concepts.html#relationships

Comment: Clear. The cars and drivers are saved but they are not accessible when browsing directly the classes. What are wrong then are the asserts.

Comment: Cars and Drivers are saved not in their class/cluster but inside the owner document Team.
If you use link instead, in team record it will save only the link to Cars documents, that at this point will be saved in his cluster.

Comment: You should use LINKSET/LINKLIST if you want to manage relationship in this way

Comment: Actually this was only a test to check how the embedded types work, and I knew what was expected, but I totally made a mistake writing the asserts. It's obvious that both car and driver classes must contain 0 documents.